# Sum the Count Visits - Sql

Tags: sql-server-2012

I came across a scenario and I am confused on how I can get it to work.

How can I `SUM` two different groups from the `COUNT` result?

```
Select Count(VisitID), Types 
From Customers
Group by Types;
```

Result gets to be like:

```
Type VisitID
A    10
B    20
C    1
```

I want the result to be as follows:

```
Type VisitID
A+C  11
```

Thanks.

Comment: A+B seems to be 30, not 11

Comment: I am sorry. I meant to say A+C. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) for example:

```
WITH CustomerCounts ([Count], [Types])
AS
(
    Select Count(VisitID), [Types] 
    from Customers
    Group by [Types]
)
Select SUM([Count]) 
From CustomerCounts
Where [Types] in ('A', 'C')
```

Comment: The CTE doesn't seem to be needed.

Comment: Yes you're right, if just counting rows, a single select should do

Comment: CTE solution by @thepirat000 worked. When I first tested, I had forgotten to filter the data for few months. I get the correct result now. Thank you so  much.

Comment: One more question! This will give me the result for "A+C" in one row. But, what if I want the second row to have a result from "E+F". Then third row to have result from "X+Y".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Select only type you want then use pivot to convert row to column then sum column like this `SELECT pv.[a] + pv.[c] from (..........)`

Comment: Thanks. This will help me format my report into Pivot table format to make the display look better.